# Pinterest Authorization failed

Tags: pinterest

We have problem with our prod pinterest application.
After getting token:

```
"{"access_token": "AabcYgRUKiaBI45HYM72teXO6fZaFQoEhVxkxaREoN3SR-
A4zAAAAAA", "token_type": "bearer", "scope": ["read_public", 
"write_public", "read_private", "write_private", "read_relationships", 
"read_write_all"]}"
```

Then we try get user info https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me
with this token `Authorization: Bearer AabcYgRUKiaBI45HYM72teXO6fZaFQoEhVxkxaREoN3SR-A4zAAAAAA`

and response

```
"{"status": "failure", "message": "Authorization failed.", "code": 3, 
"data": null}"
```

Application status is In development now. Could it been changed by pinterest? Our dev app works as expected.

Comment: This is an issue in the pinterest API. Its not related to only partners have access to API. I tested with two accounts. I get "Authorization failed." for one account but i am able to get pins for the other account using the access token.

Answer (score 3):

I got a response from Pinterest Help.

> Feb 2, 09:32 PST
>
> Thank you for providing all the information here. We're getting reports from multiple developers like yourself with the same issue. I'm going to be investigating further with our team and I'll let you know what we find!
>
> No timeline right now on a fix, but I'll let you know when I get one.

Answer (score 2):

"You're receiving that error response because your app has been denied policy approval."

Now only pinterest partners can use publish api.
Thanks for mentioning it in api doc and notification about changes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and wasted a few days trying to figure out why.

I have 2 accounts, user A and B. A is the dev and B is not a collaborator. I think that's why. The document says only collaborators can use the app without being approved by Pinterest.

The returned error message is useless. If it says so, I wouldn't have to create this ticket and the document is also lacking in my opinion.

Also, if non-collaborator can't be authenticated, the access_token step should fail first.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know that my answer is weird but I was facing this error too. I just copy pasted the url from the [Pinterest docs](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/?) then added the access token then pasted it to the url search field. The mistake which I made is that there were extra spaces in the URL For example

```
https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/pins/?
access_token=<YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN>
&fields=id,creator,note
&limit=1
```

When you paste it to the url text field the "next line" (`\n`) would be replaced with spaces like `%20`. So you should rewrite your url in one line again in your editor or text file then paste it to the chrome url field.

Your final url should be like

```
https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/pins/?access_token=<ACCESS-TOKEN>&fields=id,creator,note&limit=1
```