# Pinterest GET v1/me/boards Started Returning Authorization Failed in Approved App

Tags: api, pinterest

UPDATE: Pinterest support got back to me and confirmed that the Ver. 1 API is broken. Instead of fixing it they have offered to expedite my new app approval. I heard back from them quickly, but it's been almost a week now from submitting the materials they requested for the new app. I submitted them the same day they asked for them.

I'm having essentially the same problem that this user was:

[Pinterest Authorization failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266654/pinterest-authorization-failed)

This is an app that has been approved and working for years and we have started getting this error just in the last week when sending a GET request to https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/boards:

{"status":"failure","code":3,"data":null,"message":"Authorization failed.","endpoint_name":"get_own_boards"}

In the header I of course have the access token, which I had just received from Pinterest successfully:

"Authorization: Bearer Ah-ObYMmQFc-(REDACTED)"

The other strange wrinkle is that when I try the same request but with the access token from the Pinterest user that owns our app on Pinterest it works as expected.

I know that this has been an issue previously, but I didn't see anyone reporting it currently. The other thing is that this endpoints are being deprecated, but the new ones are only in Beta. I have an application in for the new API, which I would love to switch to, but I don't know how long that will take. Can anyone please help with this?

Answer (score 1):

I went through the approval process for V2 but they denied it. They are very strict. I don't think that a App gets approval if it's not from a known brand or company. So, say goodbye as a single dev to use the Pinterest API anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same thing with one of my apps, it seems that they shut down version 1 before opening up version 2. I've had an app that has been working flawless a while now and stopped working a couple weeks ago.

As of right now, i had to create a new app in the version 2 of their system and waiting for approval. It's been about 2 weeks and of trying to get approval but still waiting.

Create a new app and reach out to support is my best bet, haven't found any documentation for their new API or any blogs related to it being deprecated.

Comment: Support actually got back to me pretty quickly and said they'd expedite my new app. I submitted what they requested immediately but haven't heard back yet. They confirmed for me that Ver. 1 is indeed broken.

Comment: @MatthewUnderwood Its funny they say it's broken but from what i'm hearing from my users they are allowed to submit at least 1 request/post a pin.

Answer (score 0):

Pinterest support got back to me and confirmed that the Ver. 1 API is broken. Instead of fixing it they have offered to expedite my new app approval. I heard back from them quickly, but it's been almost a week now from submitting the materials they requested for the new app. I submitted them the same day they asked for them.